# Changing color of drawn shape iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

When I draw a shape in xcode for ios, how can i change the color of the final drawn shape?

```
- (void) drawArrowWithContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withSize:   (CGSize)size lineWidth:(float)width arrowHeight:(float)aheight
{
float width_wing = (size.width-width)/2;
float main = size.height-aheight;
CGPoint rectangle_points[] =
{
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + main),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 0.0, startPoint.y + main), // left point
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width/2, startPoint.y + size.height),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width, startPoint.y + main), // right point

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + main),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
};

CGContextAddLines(context, rectangle_points, 8);

CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

By default the color of this arrow is black, but I would like the user to be able to change it to black, white, or red. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` or `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`

```
- (void) drawArrowWithContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withSize: (CGSize)size lineWidth:(float)width arrowHeight:(float)aheight andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
float width_wing = (size.width-width)/2;
float main = size.height-aheight;

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,color.CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,color.CGColor);

CGPoint rectangle_points[] =
{
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + main),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 0.0, startPoint.y + main), // left point
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width/2, startPoint.y + size.height),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width, startPoint.y + main), // right point

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + main),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
};

CGContextAddLines(context, rectangle_points, 8);

CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Comment: I don't know. how can I implement those?

Comment: ok, but CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,color.CGColor); I get the error two few arguments... what shall I do?

Comment: CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to redraw it with the new color. The arrow does not exist as an object with properties which can be changed on the fly.

So change your @selector to accept a color parameter which you apply through `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` or `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`. This can be either a [CGColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html) or perhaps an integer which you can use in a switch statement to pick from some predefined colors.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but I am trying to implement it in the selector, after ArrowHeight, but I don't know what to write